# ExUnit config: starting tests without supervision tree

Tags: elixir, erlang-supervisor, ex-unit

I'm trying to imitate separate Unit and Integration tests in Elixir project. For Unit tests I don't need Supervision tree running, so ideally I'd like to use something like module tag, i.e. `@moduletag :integration` which would group tests that require an App running. I can do it manually running tests twice:

```
mix test --no-start --only integration:false
mix test --only integration:true
```

But I'd prefer some integrated solution so that I would have to just run `mix test`. There are options, such as `start` and `autorun` for ExUnit.configure/start, but they don't seem to cause any effect. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [alias](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.html#module-aliases) in the `mix.exs` that will run your test suite.

```
# also add "aliases: aliases()" to project/0 list
defp aliases do
  [testproj: ["test --no-start --only integration:false", "test --only integration:true"]]
end
```

Then try in your project directory:
`mix testproj`

Comment: Yup, doesn't seem to work. But it still feels like a workaround, the main point of the question was how to actually use ExUnit.configure to control tests. I would naively suggest that if there's run function and autorun option, then it must be possible to run tests manually twice with different params from one point.